# rails 3.1 make relative url work with a different app name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, mod-rewrite, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following issue.
Lets say my app name is MyApp.

`www.myapp.com/MyApp`
 would take me to the app page and all the sub url works well.

Now i want to change it so that `www.myapp.com/myapp-test` works including the paths and sublinks within the app.

Here is what i tried:

```
 config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/myapp-test"
```

This works only with the base root url and sub urls or links within the app does not work. It doesn't append the myapp-test.

What are the possible solutions to make this work.

Comment: are you using apache + passenger?

Comment: @MikeK. Yes thats what I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your config/routes.rb:

```
 YourApplicationName::Application.routes.draw do
   Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:script_name] = '/myapp-test'
   ...
```

See Phusion's Documentation on deploying an Rails application to a Sub-URI as well:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri

Comment: I tried that and restarted the app. But it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @newbie you've configured mod passenger with the /myapp-test context as well?

Comment: is there some documentation as how to configure mod passenger that way?

Comment: @newbie added documentation link.